# Boost binary file read error unsupported version

Tags: c++, linux, serialization, boost, binaryfiles

I'm doing sequence of serialization.

In windows system, i made binary file through boost::serialization

it seems there is no problem.

But, if i moved this binary file to linux system and load binary file
compiler says unsupported version.

I have no idea about this problem.

Can anyone help us?

Windows and linux Boost version is same. boost version is 1_63_0.

```
Adjcency_grpah LoadGraphData(char *fileName) {
    Adjcency_grpah g;
    std::ifstream ifs(fileName, std::ios::binary);
    if (!ifs) {
        cout << "Read Error" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    try {
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(g);
        cout << "Restoring Graphs Serialize Success\n" << endl;
    }
    catch (boost::archive::archive_exception e) {
        cout << "BOOST ERROR " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return g;
}
```

It still says 
"BOOST ERROR unsupported version
Time: 0"

Comment: If you could post an actual SSCCE then we could review it for any errors.

Comment: there is many components to generate binary file. so,i want to post it but, it's hard to make sample code...

Comment: Through SaveGraphData code, it generate binary file in windows. and I move it to Linux server with sftp. In Linux System, i run code that I mentioned before. Compiler says unsupported version.

Comment: We're not impressed: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/798201d67ba5805a Demonstrating creation of a binary archive from a random 100-node graph and reading it back in. Checking roundtrip using two different created graphs. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost's builtin binary archive is *not portable*. It says so in the documentation.

Instead, you should be able to use **[EOS Portable Archive](https://epa.codeplex.com/)**. It's completely drop-in compatible with Boost Serialization.

Besides this, be sure to use platform independent type identifiers (so, `int64_t` instead of `long` etc).

Comment: Is EOS Portable Archive is library for c++?

Comment: You can actually LOOK at the link. Use a secure browser if you don't like to visit web pages. It cannot be "completely drop-in compatible with Boost Serialization" if it's not C++, right?

Comment: Oh! Yeah I understand it and I'm adjusting EOS Archive!
I download zip file from website but, there isn't "portable_binary_iarchive.hpp" file in zip folder. is name changed to "portable_iarchive.hpp"?